# How to disable the Windows8 volume On-Screen-Display?

Tags: windows-8, osd

Here is a picture of what i am talking about.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xQqqMyc.jpg]

I am at my wits end with that annoying thing, please somebody help me.

Comment: Related question: [Dismiss Windows 8 Volume Box (top left corner)](http://superuser.com/questions/701573/dismiss-windows-8-volume-box-top-left-corner).

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea why the moderator *random* deleted the working solution. There is a small tool called [HideVolumeOSD](http://wordpress.venturi.de/?p=1#more-1) which can hide the overlay:

> To hide the volume OSD you can select the menu item “Hide Volume OSD”
>   or just click on the tray Icon.
>
> [image]
>
> With this item you can toggle between
>   visible and hidden volume OSD. If you exit the application, the volume
>   OSD is always restored to visible state.

You can download it [here](http://wordpress.venturi.de/?smd_process_download=1&download_id=199) and the sourcecode can be found on [github](https://github.com/UnlimitedStack/HideVolumeOSD)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Volume Step Adjuster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/volstep/) to [achieve this](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows8/comments/2gyh1e/how_to_disable_the_volume_osd/). I couldn't find a way to do this without using any third party software.

1. Download Volume Step Adjuster archive file and unzip it to a directory of your choice
2. Edit `volstep_START.bat` so the script asks to be [elevated on execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264592/1768141)
3. Edit `volstep_STOP.bat` and make similar changes
4. Add a [shortcut to `volstep_START.bat` to the startup folder](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000322.htm)

```
REM Script name: volstep_START.bat
@echo off
:checkPrivileges 
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges ) 

:getPrivileges 
if '%1'=='ELEV' (shift & goto gotPrivileges)  
ECHO. 
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation 
ECHO **************************************

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", "ELEV", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
"%temp%\OEgetPrivileges.vbs" 
exit /B 

:gotPrivileges 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal & pushd .

SET VOLUME_STEP=0.5
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v volstep /f /t REG_SZ /d "\"%~dp0volstep.exe\" %VOLUME_STEP%"
cd /d "%~dp0" ← make sure you don't forget this line 
start volstep %VOLUME_STEP%
```

Comment: Only a partial solution, OSD still pops up when hitting media mute keys

Comment: Volume Step Adjuster is open source. If you can program in C++ you could register the `VK_VOLUME_MUTE` virtual-key code and listen for the `WM_HOTKEY` message and call the [GetMute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368037(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SetMute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368064(v=vs.85).aspx) methods.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix your problem I found [mentioned on TechNet's forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4aac0f48-51fd-4030-8e1b-d313aacdd1d4/how-to-disable-the-audio-level-osd?forum=w8itprogeneral) is a 3rd-party app available at [DeviantArt](http://irzyxa.deviantart.com/art/Volume2-version-1-1-4-BETA-testing-498038518).

> **Volume²** is an advanced Windows volume control, a complete replacement for the standard Volume Control. This application lets you easily change the sound volume just by rotating the mouse wheel or by using keyboard hot keys or just mouse move on screen border. It includes an audio mixer with advanced volume controls support, a scheduler, an on-screen display, command line support, the ability to store and recall different unlimited presets via one mouse click or system-wide hot keys.

Answer (score -1):

You can stop it to start automatically.

1. Rightclick on the control-icon that belongt to the osd.
2. Than click `Settings` and turn off `Start automatically`.
3. Rightclick again and click `Close`

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer but i have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: There is a control-icon which belongs to this volume osd.

Comment: Where is this icon? In the systray?

Comment: This OSD belongs to the system, it's not provided by an application that runs on the desktop.