# Disable Windows Volume Overlay

Tags: windows-8, audio

Is it possible to disable the Windows volume box that pops up when using the keyboard to change the system volume, or at the very least, make it so it's not clickable?

[image: volume box]

Running a fullscreen application, and clicking anywhere in the top left corner after changing the volume typically ends with me waking up the neighbours while I fumble over the keyboard trying to get the sound back down to a reasonable level.

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/701573/dismiss-windows-8-volume-box-top-left-corner) asked over a year ago, but all the solution does is reduce the overlay to 5 seconds, which was already my default, and a similar question asked two years ago that suggested it may be hacked out eventually.

Cheers.

Comment: The second answer states that it only happens if you use the buildin music app. Have you tried switching to a different app?

Comment: Yep, I have Foobar set as my default program for music playback, and MPC-HC for video, the overlay still appears.

Comment: @JohnJJohnson I'm guessing that's the "similar question from 2 years ago". :) If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question I've marked as a dupe, please consider placing [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) (and some comments) on it, instead of asking the same question again.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't one of the questions I managed to find, but it looks like it has the answers. Thanks for that @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 much appreciated.

Comment: Even better then. :)  Hope it helps, that thing has annoyed me more than once as well, I'm just too lazy to disable it. ;)

Comment: Downloaded [volstep](http://sourceforge.net/projects/volstep/), ran it, problem solved. Couldn't have been simpler. Cheers again for the hand, this has been annoying me for months haha.

Comment: use this program: http://wordpress.venturi.de/?p=1#more-1