# How to reduce OSD time-out?

Tags: windows-10, display-settings, osd

In Windows 10, OSD for volume control, brightness, etc. takes almost 12 seconds to disappear.

Is there any way to change this timeout?

[image]

Comment: If you would like to go back to the pre-Windows 10 OSD, see [How to enable the old Volume control in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/enable-old-volume-control-in-windows-10/). I don't know if this simple hack still works after the latest Windows 10 update.

Comment: Well, that is for sure useful. Actually I like this new OSD, specially because you can also control it with mouse. The only problem is that it is really too long.

Comment: Try [this Windows 8 setting](http://superuser.com/a/704622/8672) (if it still applies to Windows 10).

Comment: Yes,exactly, it worked perfectly!! thanks. How can I give you the bounty?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Comment: somewhat related, regarding the extra panel that Chrome displays next to the volume popup: https://superuser.com/questions/1445405/how-can-i-prevent-chrome-from-displaying-a-volume-control-box-when-i-change-my-v

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The thread [Dismiss Windows 8 Volume Box (top left corner)](https://superuser.com/questions/701573/dismiss-windows-8-volume-box-top-left-corner/704622#704622)
describes the problem :

> When adjusting the volume in Windows 8.1, a box appears at the top
>   left corner of the screen. This box sticks around for ~13 seconds
>   before it fades away. If you attempt to dismiss it by click on it, it
>   switches to the music app.

This is the accepted answer, as adapted to Windows 10 :

1. Open Start menu > Settings
2. Click Ease of Access > Other options
3. Change the drop-down box of "Show notifications for" to the preferred time.

Another possible setting is :

1. Open Control Panel > All Control Panel Items
2. Go to Ease of Access Center > Use the computer without a display
3. Set "How long should Windows notification dialog boxes stay open"

Comment: for me win 10 the path is like this : Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Use the computer without a display\How long should Windows notification dialog boxes stay open?\5 seconds

Comment: I added this setting to my answer. I suppose that the two settings relate to different kinds of notifications. Future readers can try them both, depending on the kind of Windows 10 notification that they are getting.

Comment: Aww, I mean, this works, but I wish I could just shorten the length of the volume notification, or make it go away by right clicking it.  The volume one itself doesn't bother me, but when I'm playing music, it's taking up [so much space](http://imgur.com/a/nV9EE)

Comment: Yeah, also you can't reduce it below 5 seconds. Microsoft dropping the ball again on basic, basic stuff.... sigh.

Comment: @AlexKibler Spotify added the ability to turn off the song banner for volume now, FYI: "Edit->Settings->Display Options -> Show desktop overlay when using media keys". Not sure if you're using spotify but I do and this helps at least to stop blocking the entire damn screen.

Comment: Thanks, 2nd method worked for me for windows 11.

Answer (score 13):

You can reduce the duration, but you can't go below 5 seconds.

1. Open Start menu > Settings
2. Click Ease of Access
3. In Display tab > set "Show notifications for" what ever you want (value > 5)

[image: Settings/Ease of Access/Display dialog]

Comment: Best answer. No point digging in the registry to do this as that is hardcoded to 5 seconds minimum. Maybe someday MS will allow a custom time here.

Answer (score 10):

You can set the duration to something other than the values selectable in the menu by changing the appropriate key in registry (with regedit):

`MessageDuration` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility`

Source is option three from here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6175-change-how-long-show-notifications-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Annoying: "Entering anything lower then 5 seconds will still have a 5 second wait."

Comment: In Windows 10 version 21H2 you can have a wait shorter than 5 seconds.

Comment: @desbest, I just tested that. No you cannot have the fade-out time shorter than 5 seconds.

Comment: @Max It works for me.