# How can I prevent Chrome from displaying a volume control box when I change my volume?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, popups

In Google Chrome version 75, they've added an annoying popup that appears when I press the volume keys on my headset.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling
2. Set **Hardware Media Key Handling** to `Disabled`
3. Restart the browser to apply the changes.

[image]

Comment: Do this solution disable functionality other than removing the volume OSD banner?