# Identify software from screen overlay?

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, overlay

Google images is getting me nowhere, so I have to see if humans can recognise this overlay.

I work customer support on an online game, & this overlay [or the app behind it] is causing some issues for our users.

I'm trying to identify what app it's from.

[image]

So far, no-one has been able to discover what it might be.
Checks for common ground are coming up light. Users on Intel & AMD CPUs, AMD & NVidia graphics, so not a 'shadowplay' type thing.
So far, the only common ground is "Windows 10" but a wide variety of builds.

Our user-base is not generally technically-minded, so getting them to run any kind of test more than visual inspection doesn't work... even asking what OS they're running generally gets answers like 'Dell' or 'Best Buy' ;-)

Comment: this is buildin overlay from Windows since Windows 8, no 3rd party tool. I [posted how to disable it](https://superuser.com/a/1088958/174557) some time ago..

Comment: I have this on my surface tablet (windows 10) but not my W10 machine. Not sure if it's because of touch screen or tablet mode. On my surface, it happens if I press the physical buttons or keyboard short cut...

Comment: We don't do, "identify this thing I got" type questions

Comment: "I have this on my surface tablet (windows 10) but not my W10 machine. " - Your Surface Tablet has volume buttons, it sounds like your desktop does not have a device/hardware button to control the volume of your sound.  The sound is also muted on that device, due to the huge white x, which what the volume mixer would have if you looked at that.

Comment: You asked for a view of it in various states, see here: https://imgur.com/a/QSP6Q (note, my color scheme is based on grey... the scheme color is used for the portion under the drag block)

Answer (score 3):

This is the sound overlay in Windows 10.  This comes up when a user users a device to change the volume levels (such as keyboard buttons or a physical knob on some speakers/speakerbars).

Comment: This is the correct answer.  This toast really only appears if you have a volume control hardware button.

Answer (score 1):

It is the Toast indicator for volume control and it is currently muted.
And it would explain why your gaming end users are calling technical support about a poor experience since they've turned off their sound.

Comment: Forgive the dozy question, but is the X colour scheme "white when muted, less visible [presumably grey] when not" ? I only have access to one Win7 machine here, everything else is Mac, so I'm not actually as dozy as I may sound, just not used to newer Win versions.

Comment: The X and slider are congruent in color whether muted or 100% volume and their color is based on the color scheme. If you turned on HighContrast and customzied Yellow Titlebars, that slider will reflectively turn yellow as well.

Comment: ah, OK, ty. i don't suppose you could generate some images of various states, vol up, vol down, vol muted, so I can patch together some kind of help document for some of our ..ermm... less capable users.

Comment: @Tetsujin You could search Google images for those collateral images to compile the support document that is crucial for the ongoing benefit of YOUR tech support job much better than I could. BUT, I'll give you a headstart:    http://thewindowsclub.thewindowsclubco.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Hide-On-Screen-Volume-Indicator-in-Windows-10.jpg

Comment: I started on google images; it wasn't much help then & it isn't now, even though I know what I'm looking for. Assuming you have the very OS right there in front of you, I didn't think a couple of screenshots would be too much effort. Never mind, I'll figure it out somehow.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well that sounds like a great opportunity for a Bounty Question, the first one to finish would be rewarded some points to answer the question with some attached screenshots they had to PrtScrn and paste into MSPaint.exe, then snip, then upload for your download.

Comment: ah, yes, it's nowhere near as easy to screenshot from Windows as Mac, is it :P

Answer (score 0):

This comes from **Windows Explorer**, i.e. **explorer.exe**. Therefore, it is part of the Windows itself.

Proof:
If you exit the Windows Explorer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+right-click the taskbar and from menu select **Exit**), this will stop appearing.