# Disable large rectangle from Windows 10 Volume Overlay

Tags: windows-10, osd

We've had questions before such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/662495/how-to-disable-the-windows8-volume-on-screen-display) one about how to disable the fairly small overlay seen when adjusting volume. Recently I've seen that small overlay, which I'm happy with (because it tells me the current system volume), plus a much larger rectangle I want to disable. It looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to just keep the old overlay?

Comment: Strange how none of the answers answer the questrion, yet they are upvoted so highly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can completely disable the media OSD by using a small freeware application called [HideVolumeOSD](http://wordpress.venturi.de/?p=1). This will prevent the OSD from appearing but will keep the media-buttons functionality (play, volume...).

On the other hand, Chromium-based browsers have started to allow the use of media-keys to control the playback. You can disable it, but it will completely remove the media-keys support: navigate to `about:flags` and search for `media session`, then disable the `Media Session Service` and `Hardware Media Key Handling`:

[image]

Some other applications may allow controlling it individually, like Spotify: `Menu > Edit > Preferences > (scroll down) Display options > Show desktop overlay when using media keys`

Comment: Just to add, same thing works for Opera: about:flags -> Media Session Service -> Disable

Comment: This doesn't work for Firefox. I posted another answer below for Firefox users.

Comment: still have the volume but the giant box with the video is gone

Comment: In Chrome, I use Hotkeys For Youtube Music, once I disabled the flag and the huge overlay is gone and I can still control my music https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hotkeys-for-youtube-music/ggjkoecdjegahefiaibfnjgkebhijgpf

Answer (score 12):

**Firefox users**:

I noticed all the solutions were for Chrome. Here's what to do for Firefox.

1. Open a new tab
2. Go to `about:config`
3. Accept the risks and continue
4. Search for thr `media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled` option
5. Double click it and change it to false
6. Close and re-open Firefox

That should return it to just this, without the obnoxious overlay about *what* is being played:

[image]

Comment: Can I somehow disable the overlay, and still keep the "play/skip/pause" functionality ?
What you suggested disables it completely...

Comment: The play/next/back buttons are part of the overlay that we're hiding so I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks!  I hate this stupid overlay, what a dumb design.

Comment: Thank you! I kept finding solutions for Chrome, but not Firefox. Now I can mute my computer from the keyboard without anyone around seeing a thumbnail of what I was listening to.

Answer (score 5):

Just disable Media Session Service and it will go back to the old overlay

Comment: More precisely in my case, #hardware-media-key-handling in chrome://flags and #enable-media-session-service in opera:flags, since those were the browsers whose names were cycled through with the arrow. +1

Comment: Check my answer below for doing this in Firefox.

Comment: I don't have such "Media Session" service.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the best is to install a 3rd party volume control application, which takes over the handling of the volume adjuster media keys (the keys on the keyboard), so you simply set yourself free of all the insanity with crazy default timeout, etc. Just as an example, I use 3RVX (I'm not related to the developers on any way), and if you chose the media keys as its global hotkeys, it takes them over completely. 3rd party applications also will have more options (like, if you have a sensitive headphone, and wanted to set volume in smaller steps, which yet again something that the stock junk just doesn't let you do).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the specific question (about how to remove the media playback part of the overlay *only*), you can use the [ReMOSD](https://github.com/qt-kaneko/ReMOSD) utility - just run it at login (e.g. put it in your startup folder).