# Disable only part of the media session service for chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, vivaldi, osd

I'm using vivaldi browser, but this thing it probably coming straight from the chromium.

There's a feature that allows to go to next/prev track and shows title/cover:

[image]

It is kind of neat, but it has a few problems:

- Takes too much space
- It always shows the entire box when you modify volume
- The fading is really slow

I found how to disable it completely:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-media-session-service
```

But that takes away the ability to go the next/prev track with media control buttons <kbd>⏮</kbd> / <kbd>⏭</kbd>

Is it possible to disable only that giant rectangle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable large rectangle from Windows 10 Volume Overlay](https://superuser.com/questions/1458379/disable-large-rectangle-from-windows-10-volume-overlay)

Comment: Yeah, that software disabled the rectangle. It kind of also disabled the volume indicator altogether, so I will uninstall it.